# Geoserver is unable to accept concurrent requests when processing files

Tags: concurrency, locking, task, scaling, geoserver

I am trying to set up Geoserver as a backend to our MVC app. Geoserver works great...except it only lets me do one thing at a time. If I am processing a shapefile, the REST interface and GUI lock up until the job is done processing.

I know that there is the option to Cluster a geoserver configuration, but that would only be load balancing, so instead of only one read/write operation, I would have two instead...but we need to scale this up to at least 20 concurrent tasks at one time.

All of the references I've seen on the internet talk about locking down the number of concurrent connections, but only 1 is allowed the whole time.

Obviously GeoServer is used in production environments that have more than 1 request at the same time. I am just stumped about how to make it happen.

A few weeks ago, my colleague sent this email to the Geoserver Development team, the problem was described as a configuration lock...and that by changing a variable we could release it. The only place I saw this variable was in the source code on GitHub.

Is there a way to specify in one of the config files of Geoserver to turn these locks off so I can do concurrent read/writes? If anybody out there has encountered this before PLEASE HELP!!! Thanks!

On Fri, May 16, 2014 at 7:34 PM, Sean Winstead  wrote:

> Hi,
>
> We are using GeoServer 2.5 RC2. When uploading a shape file via the REST
>   API, the server does not respond to other requests until after the shape
>   file has been processed.
>
> For example, if I start a file upload and then click on the Layers menu
>   item in the web app, the response for the Layers page is not received until
>   after the file upload and processing have completed.
>
> I researched the issue but did not find a suitable cause/answer. I did
>   install the control flow extension and created an controlflow.properties
>   file in the data directory, but this did not appear to have any effect.​
>
> How do I diagnose the cause of this behavior?

Simple, it's the configuration lock. Our configuration subsystem is not
able to handle correct concurrent writes,
or reads during writes, so there is a whole instance read/write lock that
is taken every time you use the rest
api and the user interface, nothing can be done while the lock is in place

If you want, you can disable it using the system variable
GeoServerConfigurationLock.enabled,
-DGeoServerConfigurationLock.enabled=true
but of course we cannot predict what will happen to the configuration if
you do that.

Cheers
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

`-DGeoServerConfigurationLock.enabled=true` is referring to a startup parameter given to the java command when GeoServer is first started. Looking at GeoServer's `bin/startup.sh` and `bin\startup.bat` the approved way to do this is via an environment variable named `JAVA_OPTS`. You will see lines like

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_OPTS" ]; then
  export JAVA_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=128m"
fi
```

in `startup.sh` and

```
if "%JAVA_OPTS%" == "" (set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=128m)
```

in `startup.bat`. You will need to make those

... `JAVA_OPTS="-DGeoServerConfigurationLock.enabled=true -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"`

or define that `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable similarly before GeoServer is started.

The development team's response of "*of course we cannot predict what will happen to the configuration if you do that*", however, suggests to me that there may be concurrency issues lurking; which may be likely to surface more frequently as you scale up. Maybe you want to think about disconnecting the backend processing of those shape files from the REST requests to do so using some queueing mechanism instead of disabling GeoServer's configuration lock.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You, I figured it out. We didn't even need to do this because we were only using one login for the REST interface (admin) instead of making a new user for each repository, now the locking issue doesn't happen.